# How to get webiste root

Tags: .htaccess

I want to include a file using .htaccess, the file is opened on the
Homepage but not in other places like folders.
Here is my code block on .httaccess

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "Main/API.php"
```

the error message

`Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'Main/API.php'`

Answer (score 0):

In other folders, the string "Main/API.php" means somewhere that can't be reached.

Either place a different .htaccess in those folders, or try using absolute paths (i.e. "/var/www/www.site.com/htdocs/Main/API.php", or "/Main/API.php").